# How to Export magento database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have created magento website on localhost. I am using Version `magento 1.9.2`.
I am having problem in exporting database. 
Steps I did are from [THIS](https://www.crystalwebdesigns.com.au/export-magento-database-with-phpmyadmin.html) tutorial.

Now when I click go it downloads [This](https://ufile.io/87f12)

What am I doing wrong
This is my server description

**Database server**

```
    Database Description
    Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    Server type: MariaDB
    Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Web server**

```
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.21
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.6.21
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about phpMyAdmin and not about Magento specifically

Answer (score 4):

Run this command through terminal.

**mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p demo123 > testdatabase.sql**

- -h = Host Name
- -u = User Name
- demo123 = Database Name
- testdatabase.sql = Set file name with .sql extension

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p parishdemo > testdatabase.sql' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget upon importing to set `sql_mode` to `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` and `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to `0`. Could save you a lot of headache/pain.

Comment: yes did the same